# Neo4j 3.5 Java embedded. How to increase heap size?

Tags: java, neo4j, heap-memory, uniform-cost-search

When using Neo4j embedded with Java how do I increase the size of the heap past 2 gigabytes?

I tried to increase it to 4 Gigabytes using

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
  .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File("C:\\...\\graph.db"))
  .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, "4096M")
  .newGraphDatabase();
```

as noted in [manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/#tutorials-java-embedded-setup-config) but this appears to have no effect on the size of the heap, e.g.
Max: 2,124,414,976 B in image below.

[image]

---

**Details**

In doing a [uniform cost search](https://algorithmicthoughts.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/artificial-intelligence-uniform-cost-searchucs/) or lowest cost first search requires retaining

1. A list of each node visited
2. A queue of the cost for each relationship not processed

In using Neo4j embedded with Java the application ends with

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

To monitor the application running it is run with [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) Community 2018.3 in debug mode with [Visual VM](https://visualvm.github.io/) 1.4.2.

The IntelliJ Plugin [VisualVM Launcher](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7115-visualvm-launcher) is installed.

[image]

---

EDIT

This helps get past the problem for testing but still does not answer the question. It is posted here so that it can help others that find this question.

While I currently can not find a way increase the heap size for the JVM when creating a Neo4j graph with the Neo4j Java API, e.g.

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory()
```

or

```
new EnterpriseGraphDatabaseFactory()
```

when testing using IntelliJ

by creating the graph using

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
    .newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("C:\\...\\graph.db"));
```

and using the Intellj [Run/Debug Configurations Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html)

[image]

and editing `VM options` by adding the JVM configuration options for starting heap size `Xms` and maximum heap size `Xmx` e.g.

```
-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m
```

the heap was increased during testing to 4,4294,967,296 B and the program completed as expected.

[image]

[image]

[image]